# How can I screen record iPhone and Android screen at the same time visible right next to each other?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, mac, quicktime, android

I need to create an app video that need to show interaction b/w a iPhone and a Android phone (Galaxy).

I could use quicktime to screen record single iPhone screen.

How can I screen record iPhone and Android screen at the same time?

The two screens should be visible right next to each other showing everything that is happening on the respective screens.

Comment: Can you just put the two devices next to each other and use a camera, or other phone, to video them?

Comment: That is one way of doing it. But I was hoping quicktime and some other software could give better results.

Comment: can you just put the two recordings together in iMovie?

Comment: @timothymh could you please share a link on what you mean or how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to take two video recordings, one of the iPhone doing its 'bits' and one of the Android phone doing its 'bits'.

It sounds like you're familiar with QuickTime for the iPhone side of things, but for the Android side just do a search for *screen recorder* on the Google Play Store. You should see many options (both free and paid).

Once you have the two videos, use a video editor (such as iMovie on your MacBook) to edit the two videos into one to achieve the effect you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help? Maybe you can use QuickTime for the iPhone and the options on this link for the Android. Then export the Android video.

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/android-screen-recording-apps/